# How to fix this CORS error in Angular after no available resource hasn`t been able?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, cors

I'm writing here because I've lost my way on this problem. I've tried everything and every possible combination.
I'm working on course project with Angular. This is my first contact with Angular.
I've understood that what CORS is, why it is used and basically everything about it.
I've created my own Node.js server to work on. I've tried with and without installing cors package.
When installed I`ve provided all these different options (not at the same time of course):
This :

```
module.exports = () => (req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:4200');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Content-Type, X-Authorization');
    next();
};
```

with :
The exported module above is named createdCors when imported

```
app.use(createdCors())
```

Same thing, but as direct middleware in index.js

```
app.use((req,res,next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'HEAD,OPTIONS,GET,POST,PUT,DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, X-Authorization');
    
    
    next()
})
```

This is the cors package in index.js:

```
app.use(cors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
    credentials: true
}))
```

Another version

```
app.use(cors({credentials: true, origin: 'http://localhost:4200', allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type, X-Authorization, X-RapidAPI-Key, X-RapidAPI-Host']}))
```

Another

```
app.use(cors())
```

This is my angular interceptor :

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable, Provider } from "@angular/core";
import { mergeMap, Observable, tap } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class AppInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor{
    accessToken:string | null = localStorage.getItem(`accessToken`)

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> 
    {
       if(this.accessToken)
       {
        return next.handle(req.clone({ setHeaders: {'X-Authorization' : this.accessToken}}))
    }
        else 
        {
            return next.handle(req.clone())
        }
    }
    }

    export const AppInterceptorProvider: Provider = {
        provide:HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: AppInterceptor,
        multi:true
    }
```

This is my userService on the back-end:

```
function createAccessToken(user){
    const payload = { 
        _id: user._id,
        email: user.email,
        username: user.username
    }
    const accessToken = jwt.sign(payload,SECRET_KEY)

    return{
        email: user.email,
        username: user.username,
        accessToken,
        _id:user._id
    }
}

async function register(username,email, password){
    const existingEmail = await User.findOne({email})
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({username})

    if(existingEmail){
        throw new Error(`Email is already taken`)
    }
    else if(existingUser) {
        throw new Error(`User already exists`)
    }

    const user = await User.create({username,email,password})
    return createAccessToken(user)
}
```

This is the register.ts :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { passwordValidator } from 'src/app/shared/validator';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent {
  
  errors: string | undefined = undefined;
 
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private userService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}
  
  registerForm = this.fb.group({
    email: [``,[Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    username: [``, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
    password: [``, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
    rePass: [``, [Validators.required,passwordValidator]]
  })


  register(): void{
this.userService.register(this.registerForm.value).subscribe
    ({

      next: () => this.router.navigate([`/`]),
      error:(err)=>   {
        this.errors = err.error.error
      }

    })
  
    this.registerForm.reset()
    
  }  

  
}
```

The values are properly taken from the form and all just this CORS error is not letting me go through.

I will be happy with any advice. I don`t want to install the chrome plugin for this. I want to make it properly.

Thanks

Comment: Can I see the error itself? Sometimes a CORS error occurs if the path to the backend wrong (not available).

Comment: Yes: register:1 
        
       Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/auth/register' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: 2nd line : :3000/auth/register:1 
  
       Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: Show me your AuthService, please

Comment: Auth service in Angular :   user: null | IUser | undefined
  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }

  get isLogged(): boolean {
    if(this.user){
      return true
    }else 
    {
      return false
    }
  }

  register(data: {}){
    return this.http.post<IUser>(`${AUTH_API_URL}/register`,data).pipe(
      tap((user) => {
        this.user = user
        localStorage.setItem(`accessToken`, this.user.accessToken)
      })
    )
  }

Comment: Auth service on the back-end : async function register(username,email, password){
    const existingEmail = await User.findOne({email})
    const existingUser = await User.findOne({username})

    if(existingEmail){
        throw new Error(`Email is already taken`)
    }
    else if(existingUser) {
        throw new Error(`User already exists`)
    }

    const user = await User.create({username,email,password})
    return createAccessToken(user)
}

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible scenarios is the target URL is not using https, to be sure if that's the case open the browser as administrator:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HP7SV.png

But first check all the parameters of `httpClient` request, and here you can find an example for inspiration

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {

  googleUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes';
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {  }

  getBooks(): Observable<object> {
    let httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders()
      .set('Accept', 'application/json')

    let httpParams = new HttpParams()
      .set('q', 'Gabriel García');

      return this.httpClient.get<object>(this.googleUrl, {
      headers: httpHeaders,
      params: httpParams,
      responseType: 'json'
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: I agree with you, but this isn`t the case here. All is happenning on my localhost ports 3000 for the server, 4200 for the Angular client side

Comment: Did you tried open your app in browser as administrator? This will make us understand the situation, because the error that you have can happen in many cases, not only one possibility here I think.

Comment: Hello, yes I have and the error is exactly the same

Answer (score -1):

One of the solutions is to add proxy.conf.json in the root of the project.
Here you can find a good description:

https://levelup.gitconnected.com/fixing-cors-errors-with-angular-cli-proxy-e5e0ef143f85

Comment: I can`t believe it, but this doesn`t work too! I think there is something quite big I`m missing out...